# Trying to understand two differential forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, exterior-algebra

I'm struggling with two particular differential forms: the $\flat$ 1-form and the $\natural$ 2-form defined as follows:

> Let $X = (X_1,X_2,X_3)$ be a vector field in an open subset $O$ of $\Bbb R^3$. We define the 1-form $X^\flat$ as $$X^\flat(p)[v] = \langle X(p), v\rangle\text{ for any }p\in O\text{ and }v\in\Bbb R^3$$ and the 2-form $X^\natural$ as $$X^\natural(p)[v,w] = \det(X(p), v, w) \text{ for any }p\in O \text{ and }v,w\in\Bbb R^3.$$

They are asking me to study different operations with said operators but I need to express both forms in terms of $X_1,X_2$ and $X_3$ and $dx,dy$ and $dz$ to work with them. Could anyone please help me out in understanding how to do so? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: From what I gathered, I got $$X^\flat(p)[v] = \langle (X_1,X_2,X_3), (v_1,v_2,v_3) \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^3 X_i v_i = \sum_{i=1}^3 X_i dx_i(v) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^3 X_i v_i\right)[v]$$

$$ \begin{aligned}
X^\natural(p)[v,w]  & = \det\begin{pmatrix}
X_1 & dx_1(v) & dx_1(w)\\ 
X_2 & dx_2(v) & dx_2(w)\\ 
X_3 & dx_3(v) & dx_3(w)\\ 
\end{pmatrix} \\ & = X_1(dx_2\wedge dx_3-dx_3\wedge dx_2)
\\ & - X_2(dx_3\wedge dx_1-dx_1\wedge dx_3)
\\ & + X_3(dx_1\wedge dx_2-dx_2\wedge dx_1)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$ = 2X_1\;dx_2\wedge dx_3 + 2X_2\;dx_1\wedge dx_3 + 2X_3\;dx_1\wedge dx_2$$

But I can't get to prove certain equalities. I don't know if I have mistaken myself somewhere...

Comment: What do you know about the problem so far?

Comment: I tried considering that $X(p) = (X_1,X_2,X_3)$ and $v_i = v\;dx_i$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$. But then I'll express both expressions in a way that I can't prove the rest of the results. I'll update the heading to show my result so far.

Comment: I don't understand the $[v]$ at the end, but from the previous equality, do you not then conclude immediately that $X^\flat = \sum X_i\,dx_i$? You computation of $X^\sharp$ is correct, except for the factors of $2$.

Comment: The $[v]$ comes from the fact that $v_i = dx_i[v]$, and so we "join" them through the sum. But yeah, you can reach that result directly. But why is $X^\natural$ wrong by the factors of 2?

Comment: The expression $(\sum X_iv_i)[v]$ just makes no sense. You're evaluating a number, not a linear functional, on $v$. Check your definition of wedge product: $$(dx_1\wedge dx_2)[v,w] = dx_1(v)dx_2(w)-dx_2(v)dx_1(w).$$
You also dropped the $[v,w]$ all of a sudden in your calculation.

Comment: THAT'S RIGHT! I did it wrong! And yeah, I dropped it midway, my bad! It all works now, thanks!